# How to check if there is only one flash message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
it "flash notice should be the one and only set" do

  expect(flash[:notice]).to_not be_nil # one and only NOT nil

  expect(flash[:error]).to be_nil
  expect(flash[:alert]).to be_nil
  expect(flash[:foo]).to be_nil
  expect(flash[:bar]).to be_nil
end
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

calling `flash.keys` will return you all the keys available in flash then you can check if it has only `:notice`. You can also do the count check

```
expect(flash.keys).to eq([:notice])
expect(flash[:notice]).to_not be_nil
```

or

```
expect(flash.keys.count).to eq(1)
expect(flash[:notice]).to_not be_nil
```